# C# Sort vs Java Collections.Sort giving different results

Tags: java, c#, sorting, collections

**C# Code :**

```
public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        List<string> list = new List<string> { "johnsmith@mail.com", "john_newyork@mail.com", "john00@mail.com" };
        list.Sort();
        for(int i=0;i<list.Count;i++){
            Console.WriteLine(list[i]);
        }

    }
}
```

Result :

john_newyork@mail.com

john00@mail.com

johnsmith@mail.com

**Java Code :**

```
class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("johnsmith@mail.com");
        list.add("john_newyork@mail.com");
        list.add("john00@mail.com");
        Collections.sort(list);
        System.out.println(list);
    }
}
```

Result :

[john00@mail.com, john_newyork@mail.com, johnsmith@mail.com]

Ascii value of '_' is 95 and ascii value of '0' is 48. So ideally '0' should come before '_' in string sorting. Why C# sort places '_' before '0'?

But when I tried comparing the characters '_' and  '0'. Both the languages compare properly and keep '0' before '_'.

```
Console.WriteLine('0'>'_'); -> False (C#)
System.out.println('0'>'_'); -> false (Java)
```

Comment: You certainly came from LeetCode XD

Answer (score 2):

To sort by the ASCII value, use StringComparer.Ordinal

`list.Sort(StringComparer.Ordinal);`

Comment: Thanks. How does list.sort() work by default without any StringComparer?

Comment: @soup_boy It'd be the same as if you'd called `list.Sort(StringComparer.CurrentCulture)`

Comment: Incidentally, you can change Java to sort by culture info, but Java doesn't seem to have any constants for `Comparator<String>`, so you'd have to implement your own that uses `java.text.Collator` (use its .`getInstance` methods) to do the string comparisons.

Comment: I faced the same problem at leetcode thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

In c# you can use a `StringComparer` to specify how the comparison between the strings should work. To achieve the same behaviour as in Java you need to use `StringComparer.Ordinal`.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApp
{
    public class Test
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            var list = new List<string> { "johnsmith@mail.com", "john_newyork@mail.com", "john00@mail.com" };
            list.Sort(StringComparer.Ordinal);
            foreach (var element in list)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(element);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This prints the following on the console:

```
john00@mail.com
john_newyork@mail.com
johnsmith@mail.com
```

See also the [documentation on Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.stringcomparer.ordinal?view=netframework-4.8) for an extensive example: